# Any adapter available in Spring integration to make read/write to Spanner db?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm using Google cloud's Spanner database in my project. Does spring integration provide any adapter for that so that I can read/write to database without using spring's jpa or some other means?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. There is no dedicated adapter in Spring Cloud GCP to use Cloud Spanner as a message source/destination. However, you can use Spring Integration's standard [JDBC support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc) in combination with Cloud Spanner's [JDBC driver](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc) .

Alternatively, Spring Cloud GCP's Spring Data support could be used to define a repository, which can be used from, for example:

- for writing data: a [service acivator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator)
- for reading data: a [polling consumer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#endpoint-pollingconsumer)